# Forecast Daily Inventory with Turnover Rates and Deliveries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

#### Problem Statement

I'm working on an inventory management system using a SQL Server database that includes two tables: `Products` and `Orders`. The `Products` table stores information about various products, including their current inventory levels and turnover rates. The `Orders` table records product deliveries, including delivery dates and delivery quantities.

I need assistance in writing an SQL query that calculates the daily inventory for each product over the next 365 days, considering the product's turnover rate and upcoming deliveries. It's essential to ensure that the calculated inventory does not go below zero at any point.

**Tables and Example Data:**

Here's an example schema for the two tables and sample data:

**Products Table:**

| ID_PRODUCT | name | current_inventory | turnover_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A | 100 | 5 |
| 9 | Product I | 40 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Orders Table:**

| ID_ORDER | ID_PRODUCT | delivery_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-09-15 | 50 |
| 9 | 9 | 2023-09-23 | 120 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Expected Output:**

I need to generate a table that shows the daily inventory for each product over the next 365 days. The output table should have the following columns:

- **Date:** The date for each day over the next 365 days.
- **ID_PRODUCT:** The unique identifier of the product.
- **Inventory:** The expected inventory value for that date, ensuring it doesn't go below zero.

For example, the output for `Product A` and `Product I` for the first few days should look like this having start date `2023-09-13`:

| Date | ID_PRODUCT | Turnover_rate | Start_inventory_value | Delivery_amount | Expected_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 33 |
| 14.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 26 |
| 15.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 19 |
| 16.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 12 |
| 17.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 5 |
| 18.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 19.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 20.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 21.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 22.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 23.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 120 | 113 |
| 24.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 106 |
| 25.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 99 |
| 26.09.2023 | 9 | 7 | 40 | 0 | 92 |
| 13.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 95 |
| 14.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 90 |
| 15.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 85 |
| 16.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 80 |
| 17.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 75 |
| 18.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 70 |
| 19.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 65 |
| 20.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 60 |
| 21.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 55 |
| 22.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 50 |
| 23.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 50 | 95 |
| 24.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 90 |
| 25.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 85 |
| 26.09.2023 | 1 | 5 | 100 | 0 | 80 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**SQLFiddle:**

To speed up the process, I've prepared a SQLFiddle with the example database schema. You can access it here: [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b40bc/13).

Please provide or guide me in writing an SQL query that can generate this daily inventory report for all products, taking into account their individual turnover rates and deliveries while ensuring inventory does not go below zero.

#### What I Have Tried So Far

I've attempted to use recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs) and the LAG function, but I haven't achieved the desired results yet.

Here's the last script I tried:

```sql
WITH CTE_Calendar AS (
    SELECT TOP 365
        [date] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2023-09-13') AS DATE)
    FROM
        sys.objects
)
SELECT
    [Date]                =  cal.date
  , [ID_PRODUCT]          =  prod.ID_PRODUCT
  , [turnover_rate]       =  prod.turnover_rate
  , [delivery_amount]     =  ISNULL(ord.amount, 0)
  , [delta]               =  ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate
  , [inventory_at_date]   =  CASE
                                WHEN LAG(??, 1, prod.current_inventory) 
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY prod.ID_PRODUCT ORDER BY cal.date) +      ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate < 0
                                  THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(??, 1, prod.current_inventory) 
                                     OVER (PARTITION BY prod.ID_PRODUCT ORDER BY cal.date) + ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate
                              END

FROM CTE_Calendar AS cal

    CROSS JOIN dbo.Products AS prod
    
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders AS ord
        ON ord.delivery_date = cal.date
        AND ord.ID_PRODUCT = prod.ID_PRODUCT
```

In this script, I attempted to use a recursive CTE (CTE_Calendar) to generate a series of dates and join it with the Products and Orders tables. I also tried to use the LAG function to calculate the inventory at each date while considering the product's turnover rate and deliveries. However, I'm facing challenges in correctly calculating the inventory values and ensuring they don't go below zero.

Comment: You don't need a `CASE WHEN` construct to prevent the value is < 0. You can just use `GREATEST(value,0)`, this will return 0 whenever the value is < 0.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Even though I primarily work with older servers (2016+), it's always great to discover new, efficient tricks. I wasn't aware of the GREATEST/LEAST function, and it's definitely a technique I'll be incorporating into my SQL toolbox to improve code readability in the future. Thanks a lot for contributing this handy tip!

Answer (score 2):

From [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server/10309947#10309947)

I tweaked to use table variables, and in 2016 I couldn't use `GREATEST` so stuck with `CASE` to show 0 instead of a negative number. What this solution doesn't do is account for actually not having any inventory for a period of time - the turnover_rate from those rows returning 0 due to the `CASE` expression will show up in the math after an order comes in and brings the value back above 0. I'm not sure a set based approach can accomplish that, though it sounds like you're really looking for the first 0 so an order can be placed to prevent your inventory from ever reaching 0.

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE (
    ID_PRODUCT INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    name NVARCHAR(255),
    current_inventory INT, -- To make everything simple, data will be in INT
    turnover_rate INT -- Already calculated/Product attribute
);

INSERT INTO @Products (name, current_inventory, turnover_rate)
VALUES
    ('Product A', 100, 5),
    ('Product B', 200, 3),
    ('Product C', 150, 4),
    ('Product D', 50, 6),
    ('Product E', 300, 2),
    ('Product F', 75, 4),
    ('Product G', 250, 3),
    ('Product H', 120, 5),
    ('Product I', 40, 7),
    ('Product J', 180, 4);

DECLARE @Orders TABLE  (
    ID_ORDER INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ID_PRODUCT INT ,
    delivery_date DATE,
    amount INT
);

INSERT INTO @Orders (ID_PRODUCT, delivery_date, amount)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-09-15', 50),
    (2, '2023-09-16', 100),
    (3, '2023-09-17', 75),
    (4, '2023-09-18', 30),
    (5, '2023-09-19', 150),
    (6, '2023-09-20', 80),
    (7, '2023-09-21', 60),
    (8, '2023-09-22', 90),
    (9, '2023-09-23', 120),
    (10, '2023-09-24', 40),
    (1, '2023-09-25', 55),
    (2, '2023-09-26', 85),
    (3, '2023-09-27', 70),
    (4, '2023-09-28', 45),
    (5, '2023-09-29', 110),
    (6, '2023-09-30', 65),
    (7, '2023-10-01', 95),
    (8, '2023-10-02', 75),
    (9, '2023-10-03', 125),
    (10, '2023-10-04', 50);


WITH CTE_Calendar AS (
    SELECT TOP 365
        [date] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2023-09-13') AS DATE)
    FROM
        sys.objects
)
SELECT
    [Date]                =  cal.date
  , [ID_PRODUCT]          =  prod.ID_PRODUCT
  , [turnover_rate]       =  prod.turnover_rate
  , [delivery_amount]     =  ISNULL(ord.amount, 0)
  , [delta]               =  ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate
  , [inventory_at_date]   =  CASE WHEN (prod.current_inventory + SUM(ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate) OVER(PARTITION BY prod.ID_PRODUCT ORDER BY cal.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) > 0
                                THEN (prod.current_inventory + SUM(ISNULL(ord.amount, 0) - prod.turnover_rate) OVER(PARTITION BY prod.ID_PRODUCT ORDER BY cal.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
                                ELSE 0 END

FROM CTE_Calendar AS cal

    CROSS JOIN @Products AS prod
    
    LEFT JOIN @Orders AS ord
        ON ord.delivery_date = cal.date
        AND ord.ID_PRODUCT = prod.ID_PRODUCT
ORDER BY ID_PRODUCT, Date
```